# Python Logging Duplicate Output

Tags: python, logging

I am getting duplicate output for Python logging with custom logger. Below is the section of logging code and output. For some reason if I remove the `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` line, the logger doesn't seem to respect the `console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` line, and there is no output at all.

**Code**

```py
...
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.log:
    # Create custom logger
    logger = logging.getLogger('a')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # Create handler
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # Create formatter and add it to handler
    console_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    console_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
    # Add handler to logger
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)

    try:
        ...
    except IndexError as ie:
        logger.info(f'Test')
        ...
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error(f'Exception: {ex}')
```

**Output**

```
2022-07-11 11:29:59,409 - INFO - Test
INFO:a:Test
```

Comment: My guess is that some code somewhere (possibly from a module that you are `import`ing) is calling [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).  By default, that function uses a formatter that gives logs like `INFO:a:Test`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I remember the setting propagates to higher level (ancestor) loggers. You can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate).

I would suggest adding `logger.propagate = False` after initializing logger `a`:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('a')
logger.propagate = False
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: thank you for the help! apparently it is the `propagate` property, which kind of makes me wonder why would this be a default behavior to auto propagate to ancestor loggers.

Comment: Important subtlety: setting logger.propagate = False inside a separate function where the logger is created (containing the logging.getLogger() call) does not work. But setting logger.propagate = False after invoking such a create_logger() function does work.